# Error when trying to enable CORS in ASP.Net MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cors, same-origin-policy

I am trying to enable CORS in my ASP.Net MVC Website. The reference link I've been using can be found [here](https://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/).

I downloaded the nuget package for CORS, and applied the following changes to my code.

I added CORS module to Web.Config as below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <!---CORS-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="MvcCorsHttpModule"
         type="Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http.Cors.Mvc.MvcCorsHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
    <!---CORS-->
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*"  type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

In global.asax.cs, I added:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    //--CORS
    RegisterCors(MvcCorsConfiguration.Configuration);
}

private void RegisterCors(MvcCorsConfiguration corsConfig)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://www.youtube.com", "*", "*");
    corsConfig.EnableCors();

}
//xxCORS
```

But I am getting error with MvcCorsConfiguration:

> The name 'MvcCorsConfiguration' does not exist in the current context.

Do I need to add a namespace? Please help!

Comment: What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Comment: @AGB: I am using version 5.2. Please help if you could find what is wrong. I have been stuck with this for hours!. I am just trying to play a video from youtube and it keeps giving this error : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: I think the tutorial you're using is a little out of date.  Can you try [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.SystemWeb/) and follow [this sample](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/SystemWeb/ClaimsAuthorizeSample/ClaimsAuthorizeSample) from the project creators?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make cross domain ajax requests to your mvc application, then only you need to enable CORS.But if you are making cross domain ajax request from your mvc application to other url's then you don't need to enable CORS in your mvc application.Just tested this scenario. created a sample mvc application, then made an ajax request to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 url, it worked fine.
One solution would be, move your logic to web api and enable CORS, then call this url from your mvc or any other application

Comment: I am sorry,  I did not really understand what you said. I am playing a video from youtube using iframe. The video gets played, but i keep getting this error "Origin null not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header." Im not very familiar with json or xml. Could you please explain ? And i am not using webapi.. I am building website in MVC.

Comment: Tried recreating your problem.But i am not getting any error. I have put the following code in the cshtml page. <iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed(required id)"></iframe> It works fine in all browsers. No need to configure your mvc app to use CORS. So pls try this thing. remove the CORS setting you had done or create a basic mvc app and insert the iframe tag.check if you are getting error.

Comment: I tried the same code on a new mvc project, and have got the same error.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://gg.google.com/csi?v=2&s=youtube&action=embed& (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*').
Got this error in mozilla.